# Getting back the image url after a href.?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, image

I'm currently on a task to find out how is it possible to get back the image source that 
I've previously linked to a new page?

**Example:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `test`.image FROM `table` WHERE `test`.id='123'";
 if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?><a href="itinery.php"</a><img src=" <?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
}
}
```

I am currently using SQL as well to echo out the images, so given that I clicked on the image that will link me to test.php, how do I actually get back the image source previously that I called? Pardon my poor english, thank you!

Cheers,

TechNewbie.

Latest Update 1)

I tried putting in id in the a href and calling it in itinery.php, wonder if it will work? Will post updates here :)

Latest Update 2)

I realised I need to get a href value once I clicked the image source because it will lead me to itinery.php, correct me im wrong. Figuring out a way to do it. :)

Comment: It is really not an ideal way of working with HTML. Try step back and rethink the problem, you really should **first record the image link then echo it out**. Trust me, it happened to me before, rethinking the situation really helped making the real solution.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I understand where your coming from.

But given that all the images all link to the same itinery.php, I've to do it in way that I must try to retrieve the a href value, trying any possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

#### <sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<a href="itinery.php?fw=a.jpg"><img src="a.jpg"></a>
<a href="itinery.php?fw=bob.jpg"><img src="bob.jpg"></a>
```

This is a **common practice** of seeing where things come from where in the internet, e.g. finished downloading a file on a download service site where it recommend you another thing. Usually, they will hide the behind-the-scene from the visitors for aesthetic and bookmarking reasons.

Where `fw` means "forward" and the get value is the image source.

So in your `itinery.php`, you add these lines:

#### <sub>PHP:</sub>

```
if(isset($_GET["fw"])) {
    $img_src = $_GET["fw"];
}
```

This was what I meant. If you would like to know how to hide the `?fw=bob.jpg` part from the URL or anything else, please let me know too.

---

### Addition: Hiding the address

This uses JS, which altered the browser's history and address to anything you entered. Good for **when users ever wanted to bookmark the page, they won't need to deal with the code again**

#### <sub>JS:</sub>

```
var stateObj = { foo: "nothing happened" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "Itinery", "itinery.php");
```

or shortly:

```
history.pushState("nothing happened", "Itinery", "itinery.php");
```

please see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Just echo the script in PHP when a `fw` is get.

#### <sub>PHP:</sub>

```
if(isset($_GET["fw"])) {
    $img_src = $_GET["fw"];
    echo '<script>history.pushState("nothing happened", "Itinery", "itinery.php");</script>';
}
```

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thank you so much, that was certainly a life-saver.

I am definitely interested to know how to hide the ?fw=bob.jpg, learning is always the fun process to go. And till now I didnt know there existed a fw till now, thank you once again!

Comment: You're welcome. I struggled this problem not far back in time too. Me thinking about this solution alone was sure proud of myself too. :P hehe

Comment: Also, relating to your "didnt know there existed a fw", you can name it whatever you want, it's just a variable. Here's a site you may want to visit: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php

Comment: Wow, thanks Daniel, that certainly shed alot of light. There are so many things to learn :)